# Actionscript parse currency to get a number

Tags: actionscript, currency

i used a CurrencyFormatter to parse 2 number into its currency representation

currencyFormat.format("10" + "." + "99") ---> $10.99

I'm curious if there is a way to parse a string "$10.99" back to a number / double ?
so it is possible to get the value on the left side of the decimal and right side of the decimal.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this a number of ways.  Here are 2 off the top of my head:

```
function currencyToNumbers($currency:String):Object {
    var currencyRE:RegExp = /\$([1-9][0-9]+)\.?([0-9]{2})?/;
    var val = currencyRE.exec($currency);
    return {dollars:val[1], cents:val[2]};
}


function currencyToNumbers2($currency:String):Object {
    var dollarSignIndex:int = $currency.indexOf('$');
    if (dollarSignIndex != -1) {
        $currency = $currency.substr(dollarSignIndex + 1);
    }
    var currencyParts = parseFloat($currency).toString().split(".");
    return {dollars:currencyParts[0], cents:currencyParts[1]};
}

var currency:Object = currencyToNumbers('$199.99');
trace(currency.dollars);
trace(currency.cents);

var currency2:Object = currencyToNumbers2('$199.99');
trace(currency2.dollars);
trace(currency2.cents);
```